# please help me with the GROK pattern for below log message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Below is the log message coming to `Kibana`, but we need to add filters on any one of the segregations below as each one is representing some unique criteria.

Please help me with the `GROK` pattern for this.in the below format the actual message is after rest keyword

{"@timestamp":"2021-02-19T10:27:42.275+00:00","severity":"INFO","service":"capp","pid":"19592","thread":"SmsListenerContainer-9","class":"c.o.c.backend.impl.SmsServiceImpl","rest":"[SmsListener] [sendSMS] [63289e8d-13c9-4622-b1a1-548346dd9427] [synemail] [ABSENT] [synfi] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] [N/A] [N/A] [End Method]"}

Answer (score 0):

To this kinf of use case, you have [this online tool](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) that provide a quick way to test/validate expression.

This expression must match our data line :

```
^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s*\] \[%{DATA:thread}?\] \[%{DATA:class}?\] \[%{DATA:action}?\] \[%{DATA:id}?\] \[%{DATA:field1}?\] \[%{DATA:field2}?\] \[%{DATA:field3}?\]
```

So in file configuration contexte this looks like this :

```
  filter{
    grok {
        match => { 
          "message" => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s*\] \[%{DATA:thread}?\] \[%{DATA:class}?\] \[%{DATA:action}?\] \[%{DATA:id}?\] \[%{DATA:field1}?\] \[%{DATA:field2}?\] \[%{DATA:field3}?\]" 
          }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response !!

Comment: i have modified the pattern as you suggested but it is also not working and seeing this error on logstash console _grokparsefailure

Comment: filter{
    grok {
        match => { 
          "message" => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s*\] \[%{DATA:thread}?\] \[%{JAVACLASS:class}?\] \[%{WORD:method}?\] \[%{DATA:id}?\] \[%{DATA:field1}?\] \[%{DATA:field2}?\] \[%{DATA:field3}?\]$" 
          }
    }
  }

Comment: What is not working? Some pattern must not match with data?

Comment: _grokparsefailure is showing in tags section and when i tried to see the data in kibana it is still showing the old format

Comment: Yes, you have to keep the complete expression with \[ not just [, because this not correctly interpreted. Could you send the line that have  _grokparsefailure ?

Comment: {
    "@timestamp" => 2021-02-18T11:08:43.544Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
          "path" => "C:/opt/testing/log/cms-23.log",
          "type" => "syslog",
       "message" => "[2021-02-18 16:38:42,927] [INFO] [XNIO-1 task-1] [FileStorageServiceImpl] [uploadBytesToS3] [83b4565b-8eba-413c-a2d4-e3e8be62fb91] [synemail] [83b4565b-8eba-413c-a2d4-e3e8be62fb91] [::End method::]\r",
          "host" => "OSLT30334-SE"
}

Comment: Ok, remove the $ at the end of expression. I edit my answer

Comment: Can you help me the grok pattern for the below pattern

Comment: {"@timestamp":"2021-02-19T10:27:42.275+00:00","severity":"INFO","service":"capp","pid":"19592","thread":"SmsListenerContainer-9","class":"c.o.c.backend.impl.SmsBackendServiceImpl","rest":"[SmsListener] [sendSMS] [63289e8d-13c9-4622-b1a1-548346dd9427] [synemail] [ABSENT] [synfi] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] [N/A] [N/A] [End Method]"}

Comment: in the above log after rest string is the actual message need to filtered out.

Comment: I guess you must post another question, this one is a new data line

Comment: Yeah i have captured the log from my local log file yesterday when i seen in Kibana log format is different so updated the log format.